# procmail to deliver mail to 2 maildir locations

Tags: backup, postfix, dovecot, procmail, maildir

Now I am having Postifx --> procmailrc---> maildire---> dovecot   and I need to have another maildir in another folder inside /root as a backup at the same time having /$home/maildir ?

First and second both should have mails in maildir format.

How can I instruct procmail to have second maildir in another location /root ?.

If this second location need be another server, how can I send the mail to there?

my current procmailrc file is at /etc and which is --->

```
:0fw: spamassassin.lock
* < 256000
| /usr/bin/spamassassin

:0
* ^X-Spam-Status: Yes
/home/spammail/Maildir/

LOGFILE="/var/log/procmail.log"
DEFAULT="$HOME/Maildir/"
MAILDIR="$HOME/Maildir/"
```

Your help expected.

Thanks,

lasantha

Answer (score 1):

Youc can use `c` flag (carbon copy).

Add this lines before the one with `:0`

```
:0c:
/your/backup/Maildir/
```

Comment: To deliver to a different server, change the action line to `! address@otherserver`.  This will add another `Received:` header and possibly change or add some other headers.